# How to integrate MyFaces with Spring

Tags: spring, jsf, integration, myfaces

In my logon.xhtml, I have following code that involve my backing bean to perform correspopnding logon through spring security.

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" id="login" value="Login"
action="#{logonController.doLogin}" />
```

My backing bean defines as the following.

```
@Component
@ManagedBean(name="logonController")
@SessionScoped
public class LogonController
{
. . .
public String doLogin() throws ServletException, IOException {
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
            .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");
    dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
            (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    logger.debug("in LogonPageController ");
    return null;
}
}
```

In order to integrate spring with JSF, I have also added the following to the faces-config.xml.

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

Moreover, two standard spring listeners have also be inclued in the web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

I have tried the above setting in mojarra + tomcat and it should be able to trigger the logon() function of my backing bean when user click on the Logon button. However, when I swith to TomEE with MyFaces, this won't work. I have the following maven dependency in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
    <version>${myfaces-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${myfaces-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any thing that I need to add in order to make it work with MyFaces? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Two companies say that compatible each other.but no substantiating examples.I hope, someone shows an example instead of saying "compatible".